# using Jenkins for iOS build

Tags: ios, jenkins

I am new to jenkins, I am trying to build my iOS application on simulator via jenkins. I am using this command,

```
xcrun xcodebuild -project Name.xcodeproj \
    -scheme Name \
    -sdk iphonesimulator \
    -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,OS=15.5,name=iPhone 12' \
    CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO \
    build
```

The build is successful but I can't see the application built on my simulator. And How can I build the same app on real device via jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

The command that you are running will build the application **FOR** the simulator (this usually means that it will build the application for the 64-bit architecture).

That doesn't mean that it will actually copy/install the application to the simulator for you, its literally just building the application with that architecture so that it is compatible with the simulator.

To build for device, replace your destination with `-destination generic/platform=iOS` you would also need code signing